# SharePoint: Change item in the source table (lookup table)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am new in SharePoint. I have multiple lists with lookups. In list A (target) I have multiple columns from the list B (source). Currently I have data in both lists.
Now I need to change some values for some items (rows) in list B (source). I am curious if I change the rows in list B, will it affect other lookup data in list A (where previous (old) row data is used)?
I am sorry if it is a trivial question. I am new and data is quite critical data to make a mistake.

Can changing (some) data in the source list cause issue in the target list?

Comment: Lookup values are read-only, so you will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change (some) data in the source list, the source data selected by the lookup column will automatically change accordingly. But no error will be reported:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question. Whenever I add a new item to the target list I pick the value from lookup list by using "Title" (for instance, "Get information from:" - List B, "In this column:" -Title). If I change or delete "Title" value in the source list, will it cause an issue in the old target list records where those deleted (changed) Titles are used?

Comment: There will be no error, delete the "title" value in the source list, and it will be automatically deleted in the target list.